# What were the Olympic Chinese table tennis players yelling when they scored?

Tags: pronunciation

Watching the men's team table tennis gold medal match in the Tokyo 2020(1) Olympics, I noticed that the Chinese players were yelling something every time they scored. I tried googling to see what they were yelling, but all the articles I found said that ping pong players yell "cho" or "cho-le" when they score. What I was hearing sounded nothing like "cho", and *maybe* sounded like "cho-le" if the "cho" was nearly silent. It definitely sounded like a single syllable word rhyming with "way". I'm guessing they were saying "dui" (对), but can anyone confirm what they were actually saying?

Comment: I guess it is 再來/Zài lái/ (come again/ once more/ continue --> start the next point (imply "I've won this one")

Comment: Troy.
You can see the explanation here on a Chinese Q&A website Zhihu.
https://www.zhihu.com/answer/179392214

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.xinhuanet.com/world/2016-08/12/c_129224485.htm

This article said that the shouts of players after scoring have no practical meaning, just to relieve pressure“这是一种情绪的释放”. The shouts of players are different, there are "sa", "ja", "yo", "ho", "ju", etc. I watched the game you asked, their shouts are close to "troy" or "shoy", they have no practical meaning and no corresponding Chinese characters, just a roar.

Comment: I saw a game and the subtitle for this yell was indicated as "走你" (go away!), I  think it is a natural reaction when a 'threat' is dealt with. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FU2DXeExjKA&t=1255s

Answer (score 5):

https://pingsunday.com/why-do-table-tennis-players-say-cho/

I used to play Table Tennis competitively as a kid. Essentially, it's a way to hype yourself, build confidence, while psyching your opponent out after a point.

"Cho" is really derived from 球 (ball). A great way to hear this is to hear someone say 好球 (good ball) with the 4th tone on 球. I've also heard that "Cho-le" can be heard as 球来 (ball come).

The meaning of the sound isn't as important as the feeling it conveys. The purpose is to simultaneously build oneself up while challenging the mental stability of the opponent during a match.

Answer (score 1):

As a Chinese, I think cho-le phonetically sounds like a local colloquial “出嘞” （chu le） means the ball went out of bound, and therefore they scored. Simply it can be used as Chu (出！）means the ball went out of the table.

Answer (score -1):

Let's be honest. **操**/**肏** cào is the big one. You can hear this being exclaimed during a lot of sporting events. Even on a Saturday morning at your local Decathlon, during a friendly game of soccer.

This was also evident during the women's badminton match:

[Chinese badminton player's cursing at Tokyo 2020 riles South Koreans](https://edition.cnn.com/2021/08/03/sport/south-korea-china-tokyo-2020-badminton-spt-intl/index.html)

> Chen Qingchen, 24, could be heard shouting a popular Chinese slang term, translated loosely as "f**k"​ in Mandarin, throughout the live televised broadcast of her women's doubles match against South Korea on Tuesday, July 27.

If there is anything that could be understood as "cho" or "cho-le" as the announcers did mention in their commentary. It's more likely to be: Fuck.

Comment: This swearing may be used when the opponent is scoring. Even that, the player wouldn't be allowed to use that word in an international game.

Comment: @r13 Here's just one example from the match OP asked about: https://youtu.be/VTCDQYYKA9o?t=951 @ ~15:52.

Comment: The video is not available or blocked. Tried another one, only heard yelling from the audience.

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is "Cho-lei".
Coach EmRatThich (Chinese table tennis coach) has explained here.

[why table tennis shout "Chooo!" and "Cho-lei!"](https://pingsunday.com/why-do-table-tennis-players-say-cho/)

You can search on Google "the meaning of Cho-lei table tennis".